# Múltiplos de 2,4 y 5

Tags: c#

Hacer un programa que sume todos los números múltiplos de 2, 4 y 5 a la vez del 1 al 1000. Ej. El 20, cumple con las 3 condiciones.

Yo lo he hecho así, pero a la hora de sumar,no me genera la respuesta correcta

```
    int i=1, suma =0;

    while(i <= 1000)
    {
        if(i % 2 ==0 && i % 4==0 && i % 5==0)
        {   Console.WriteLine(i);
            suma = suma+i;
        }
        else
        {
            suma =0;
        }      
        i++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("La suma total es: "+suma);
```

Answer (score 6):

El problema es el else de tu código:

```
 else
 {
     suma =0;
 }
```

Por ejemplo, cuando `i = 20`, `suma = 20`, pero en la siguiente iteración, `i = 21`, `suma = 0` porque no se cumple la condición. Si eliminas el else, deberías obtener la suma correcta.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que estás en PHP o java debería ser así:

```
 while(i <= 1000)
{
    if(i % 2 ==0 && i % 4==0 && i % 5==0)
    {   Console.WriteLine(i);
        suma += i;
    }
    else
    {
        suma +=0;
    }
    i++;
}
Console.WriteLine("La suma total es: "+suma);
```

Comment: ¿Por qué es necesario hacer `suma += 0`?

Comment: Esta respuesta tiene 2 problemas. Primero la pregunta es en c#. Y despues, tiene exactamente el mismo error que cometio el usuario al hacer el else. No va a traer la suma deseada.

Answer (score 1):

```
 int i=1, suma =0;

 while(i <= 1000)
 {
     if(i % 2 ==0 && i % 4==0 && i % 5==0)
     {   Console.WriteLine(i);
         suma +=i;
     }
     i++;
 }
 Console.WriteLine("La suma total es: "+suma);
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).